# How to clean white handlebar tape?

Tags: cleaning, handlebar-tape

I have bought not so long ago (about two month) brand new and the shiny white from my handle tap have become pretty dirty:

[image: handlebar]

I am tempted to just change the tape to another color - that would be problem solved for me - but that would basically be a dirty hack. How can I clean the white tape and remove the dirt?

Comment: For those wondering yes I have my bike in my bedroom, i.e: http://p.chmouel.com/inbedroom.jpeg

Comment: You mean everybody doesn't?

Comment: Wrap it with white (or orange or blue) hockey tape.

Comment: (Or wash your hands.)

Comment: Why wash it? You worked hard to accumulate that much dirt - it just shows that you ride a lot. I thought my white tape was going to be a P.I.T.A. to keep clean, too but once I realized it's a badge of honor I just let it go.

Comment: If Simple Green is so good, why does Simple Green make the Simple Green For Bikes product which is specifically formulated to be safe for plastics, rubber, and paint? Duh, because normal Simple Green is not good for plastics,rubber and paint for long term use so yeah you get away with it initially but it breaks down the plasticizers in plastics and when you eventually do see the handlebar tape destroyed you assume it is normal wear and tear and never figure out you created pre-mature death from using regular Simple Green for long term cleaning. Armoral figured this out a long time ago and prov

Comment: If it's that's dirty, Turps does a good job

Comment: @Cleaningjunki  Turns is great for cleaning but it leaves a residue, and there's always a risk to rubber and some plastics.  The brake hoods are right there and if they go tacky cos of the solvents, OP will need to replace them at a much larger cost than the cheaper bartape.

Comment: Another option is to leave the white bartape on the hooks but to wrap the tops and ramps with a darker colour.   I used Black and Red on a bike, to match the paint theme and it looked sharp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grab some of the disinfecting wipes in the round containers that you normally use for kitchen counters, etc. I like the Clorox brand in the yellow (Lemon Fresh!). Wrap around bars and squeeze a bit as you twist/rotate in the same direction as the wrap.

With cork based wrap this is fairly effective. With some of the slicker surfaced wraps (Lizard, etc), it's downright awesome. If you start cleaning with the wipes on a regular schedule your wrap will get even cleaner over time.

Comment: BTW: this works for other color wrap as well...it's surprising how much better black (non-cork) wrap looks after a good clean.

Answer (score 3):

I use a citrus degreaser and its great. I clean my entire bike with it, but it gets the sweat and oils off the tape so the dirt stops sticking.

Answer (score 3):

I use a cleaning product called Simple Green. It's bio-degradable ( good for the environment ) and really does a complete cleaning job! You can mix it at different strengths from a 1/2 gallon or 1 gallon refill size. It comes in a spray bottle initially. I use it to clean my bicycle rather than soap and water. It is safe to use and doesn't harm the paint. Just spray it on the bike or a soft cloth, and wipe the grease and dirt/dust off easily. No need to rinse the bike. It should gently remove the dirt/sweat from your handlebar tape. If the grips are cork, use just a little Simple Green on a soft cloth and wipe gently and remove from the tape. Don't allow the Simple Green to stay on the tape for an extended period ( which is determined by the strength you mix the Simple Green ). Same goes for wiping the bike using Simple Green. Don't allow it to dry on the paint. Wipe it on and with a dampened second cloth, wipe it off. You'll find more uses for Simple Green besides your bike! If you're married, better buy two bottles so your spouse can have their own bottle!

Comment: word of warning on simplegreen. If you let sit too long, like say a year, it will bleach things. Especially in the heat. Something about it breaks down over time and it can damage things when its old.

Comment: I love Simple Green, but no longer leave it on or let parts soak in it for very long... (http://velonews.competitor.com/2005/11/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-qa-with-lennard-zinn-not-so-simple-green-2_9216)

Comment: The link above has a posting from a rep @ Simple Green which has a (new) product, Extreme Aircraft and Precision Cleaner, they claim is better for use on bicycle parts than plain old Simple Green. You can get it here: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001VXU7OE

Answer (score 3):

Dishwashing liquid and a small amount of baking soda, warm water, on an old sock or rag. 
Wipe with damp rag. 
Clean and bright.

Most of the dirt on my handlebar tape is from cleaning debris from tires while cycling.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Cif or Jif as it used to be called. Its a cream bathroom and kitchen surface cleaner. Works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

I've never gone wrong cleaning wraps using a soapy rag and elbow grease. I use an old bit of towel and dish soap. This has done a great job cleaning up thoroughly bike-greased and sweat-upon wraps.

Answer (score 1):

baby wipes all day son - best, cheapest option to rim to rim, and you can even get them in organic!  I've even used coconut oil as an on the spot bike lube.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @face. As a new user, I encourage you to check out our [help] to learn how this site works. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Use your old toothbrush and a normal toothpaste

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Can you expand your answer with more details?  Have you done this yourself?  Did it work well or was it less effective than other cleaning methods?